# HDFS-sink connector: No FileSystem for scheme: http

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using the documentation of `confluent`, but when I add a `hdfs-sink` connector, I get this Error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: http
```

Could any one help me please?

Comment: Unless you show us your code, it is impossible to accurately diagnose your issues and help you.

Answer (score 0):

HDFS Sink connect doesn't work with HTTP urls (such as HttpFs).

You need to give a supported [Hadoop Compatible FileSystem](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HCFS) such as

- **hdfs://**
- **file://** (Will write to local disk on individual Connect workers in Distributed Mode, works best only in Standalone mode)
- **s3a://**  (Assuming hadoop-aws on CLASSPATH)
- **wasb://** (Assuming hadoop-azure on CLASSPATH)